# Calling a asmx webservice from wcf web service - ContractFilter mismatch

Tags: wcf, asmx

I have a very old asmx webservice.  Due to restrictions i cannot call this service directly.  So i am creating a WCF web service, which will act like a proxy between the client and the actual web service.  My client application, which was actually calling the asmx web service is now going to call the wcf service.  Also this way, i should not make any code changes in my client.

I created the service successfully.  While trying to access from my client, i get this message.  The message with Action  cannot be processed at the receive, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.

I tried to match my proxy web service to match the existing webservice.  May be i am missing something.  Please help.

Comment: What restrictions are you experiencing calling the ASMX?  Are they technical or political?  Do you know if the call is failing to call the proxy service or is between proxy service and the ASMX service?  Might want to try putting up a hello method that your client can call to check if it is the proxy service.  Can you post a code sample?

Comment: Restrictions are due to security reasons.  Call is not failing at Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The ContractFilter mismatch is almost always due to versioning problems. You could try to update your "Connected Services" reference to WCF Service or manually rerun SvcUtil or use ChannelFactory of the ServiceContract of your WCF Service by putting this in a shared class library for the Client and the WCF service. You can also add more logging in WCF and use the util **SvcTraceViewer** to see where it fails. Add the following to the web.config of your WCF service for example:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
             <add name="messages"
             type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
      </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>

<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
<messageLogging 
     logEntireMessage="true" 
     logMalformedMessages="false"
     logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
     logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
     maxMessagesToLog="3000"
     maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
</diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then you can open up the .svclog file in SvcTraceViewer and see why it fails. But if the client call already fails, it is possible that you will not see any log item anyways. So moving your Service Contract to a Shared class library and let the client use a ChannelFactory will ensure that your clients are more up to date with the service. Now it is also possible that it is the WCF service that fails a call against the older ASMX service, then firing up Fiddler is perhaps the next step (or add more logging in the old ASMX service).